# Powershell: addin line into the .txt file

Tags: powershell

I have a text (`.txt`) file with following content:

```
Car1
Car2
Car3
Car4
Car5
```

For changing `Car1` for random text I used this script:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\boris.magdic\Desktop\q" -Filter *.TXT | 
Foreach-Object{ 
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName 
    $content | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "Car1", "random_text"  } | Set-Content $_.FullName 
}
```

This is working ok, but now I want to add one text line under `Car2` in my text file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just chain another `-replace` and use a new line!

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\boris.magdic\Desktop\q" -Filter *.TXT | 
Foreach-Object{ 
    $file = $_.FullName
    $content = Get-Content $file
    $content | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "Car1", "random_text" -replace "(Car2)","`$1`r`nOtherText" } | Set-Content $file 
}
```

First thing is that `| Set-Content $_.FullName` would not work since the file object does not exist in that pipe. So one simple this to do it save the variable for use later in the pipe. You can also use the `ForEach($file in (Get-ChildItem....))` construct.

The specific change to get what you want is the second `-replace`. We place what you want to match in brackets to that we can reference it in the replacement string with `$1`. We use a backtick to ensure PowerShell does not treat it as a variable.

We can remove some redundancy as well since `-replace` will work against the strings of file as a whole

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -Filter *.TXT | 
Foreach-Object{ 
    $file = $_.FullName 
    (Get-Content $file) -replace "Car1", "random_text" -replace "(Car2)","`$1`r`nOtherText" | Set-Content $file
}
```

While this does work with your sample text I want to point out that more complicated strings might require more finesse to ensure you make the correct changed and that the replacements we are using are regex based and do not need to be for this specific example.

**.Replace()**

So if you were just doing simple replacements then we can update your original logic.

```
Foreach-Object{
    $file = $_.FullName 
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName 
    $content | ForEach-Object { $_.replace("Car1", "random_text").replace("Car2","Car2`r`nOtherText")} | Set-Content $file
}
```

So that is just simple text replacement chained using the string method `.Replace()`

Comment: and let to see on another scenario.
i want to get a filename together with random_text: random_text/filename


Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -Filter *.TXT | 
Foreach-Object{ 
    $file = $_.FullName 
    (Get-Content $file) -replace "Car1", "random_text/" $file | Set-Content $file
}


this doesnt workin.

Comment: @BorisMagdič Well first I see that you are using my path not yours. Thats an accident from my copy paste. What not working exactly?

Comment: everything working fine with yor script, i rreplace the path ofrkzzz.


Get-ChildItem ".\" -Filter *.TXT | `
Foreach-Object{
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    #filter and save content to the original file
    $content | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "Boris", "Boris_" } | Set-Content $_.FullName
}

but now i just want to get a fullname of file where change is done after replaced text, somthing like this: Boris_"filename_without_.TXT" .

how to procced with $file = $_.FullName in this case? Im not sure how to use the powershell to add name of file after replaced word.

Comment: i found something like this: 

Get-ChildItem ".\" -Filter *.TXT | 
Foreach-Object{ 
    $lol = $file
    $file = $_.FullName
    $content = Get-Content $file
    $content | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'Boris', ("Boris=" + $file)} | Set-Content  $file 
}


this is that im was looking for, but the problem is that i received full path of file, but i want only the name of file without extension.

Comment: i got it mateee: 

Get-ChildItem ".\" -Filter *.TXT | 
Foreach-Object{ 
    $lol = (Get-Item '.\').Basename
    $file = $_.FullName
    $content = Get-Content $file
    $content | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'Boris', ("Boris=" + $lol)} | Set-Content  $file 
}

=]]]]]]]]]]]]]